# Duplicate results due to multiple left outer joins

Tags: sql

My query is as below

```
select DISTINCT
    wftransaction.PERSONID,
    pr.PRNUM, 
    pr.DESCRIPTION, 
    pr.PR1,
    prline.GLDEBITACCT, 
    wftransaction.TRANSDATE,
    prstatus.CHANGEBY
    prstatus.CHANGEDATE, 
    prstatus.STATUS, 
    prstatus.MEMO 
from pr
left outer join wftransaction pr.PRID = wftransaction.ORNERID and wftransaction.OWNERTABLE ='PR' 
left outer join prline on pr.PRNUM = prline.PRNUM 
left outer join prstatus on pr.PRNUM= prstatus.PRNUM
```

The result given by my query has duplicate results.Please do help me eliminate the redundant/repeating outputs.

When I put distinct this is what happens, https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2jnN.jpg,

I should only see 2 outputs with the same "STATUS" i.e.(COMPOSING) or (APPR) since they have different "GLDEBITACCT", other than that, there should be no more duplicates.

[***This is the picture of my Code and Result Set***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2jnN.jpg)

Comment: Please don't add images. Create code blocks.

Comment: can you please create sqlfiddle or share sample db script?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should be using inner join because if left join where being used all data from table A will repeatedly shows as the table B has its foreign key, or might sometimes you are lacking of WHERE clauses it depends on your query, it will be more helpful to others if you can paste the whole query and their structures with expected results.

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/database/visual_sql_joins.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Good idea will be to place a simple DISTINCT clause in the query

```
select DISTINCT
    wftransaction.PERSONID,
    pr.PRNUM, 
    pr.DESCRIPTION, 
    pr.PR1,
    prline.GLDEBITACCT, 
    wftransaction.TRANSDATE,
    prstatus.CHANGEBY
    prstatus.CHANGEDATE, 
    prstatus.STATUS, 
    prstatus.MEMO 
from pr
left outer join wftransaction pr.PRID = wftransaction.ORNERID and wftransaction.OWNERTABLE ='PR' 
left outer join prline on pr.PRNUM = prline.PRNUM 
left outer join prstatus on pr.PRNUM= prstatus.PRNUM
```